# How do I get an iTunes podcast into an Android phone?

Tags: itunes

I want to listen to an iTunes podcast in Podcast Addict app on my Android phone. It doesn't come up in the search engine in the app, and I can't find the link (RSS I guess) on the iTunes site to plug it in manually.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Podcast Addict v2.3 supports searching and listening to iTunes podcast directly from the app.

You can subscribe to iTunes podcasts (just copy/paste or press on the URL) and you can also browse the iTunes database, so the podcast you're trying to listen will now show up.